# Programming graphics in assembler?

Tags: graphics, assembly

I've developed a running Super Mario Sprite using Visual C++ 6.0 and DirectX. But this isn't very satisfying to me (raping a 3D-Multimedia-framework for displaying a 2D sprite only), so I would like to be able to program an animated sprite using C and assembler only.

So, when looking to old games (Wolfenstein, for example) it looks that most of the game is written in C and everytime it comes to graphics output there is the use of assembler.

Unfortunatly when trying to use this old assembler code there is always the error message "NTVDM.exe has found an invalid instruction" so this things don't seem to work nowadays.

Is there any tutorial on graphics programming in assembler that is still usefull?

(I don't want to use any bloated frameworks or libraries, I just want to develop everything on my own. WinAPI would be OK for creating a full screen window and for catching user input, but not for graphics because I read GDI is too slow for fast graphics.)

I'm using WindowsXP and MASM or A86.

Comment: So don't use "old" assembler code.  Were you trying to run 16-bit DOS code or something?

Answer (score 15):

I totally agree with samcl

The main reason for not using assembler anymore is that you cannot access the Videomemory anymore. Back in the early days (you mentioned Castle Wolfenstein) there was a special video mode called [0x13h](http://www.brackeen.com/vga/basics.html) where your graphic was just a block of memory(each pixel was a palette color ranging from 0-255<--1 Byte) You were able to access this memory through this specific video mode, however, today things are much more complicated

Today you have very fast Videomemory and using your CPU for accessing it will just tear down all performance, as you CPU is connected through PCI-Express/AGP/PCI/VESA-LOCALBUS/ISA (<- remembering anyone!?)

Graphicsprogramming is  often a lot of read and write accesses(read pixel, check if it is transparent, multiply with alpha, write pixel, etc.)
The modern memory Interfaces are much slower than direct access **inside** the graphic card. That's why you really should use shaders, as Robert Gould suggests. In this way you can write faster and easier to understand code and it will not stall your GFX-Memory.

IF you are more interested in GFX Programming, you can wet your appetite with [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/), a community dedicated to shaderbased effects complete with WebGLbased Shadercode execution.

Also your beginner assembler code will be pretty lame. in quality as in performance. Trust me. It needs a lot of time for optimizing such primitive code. So your compiled C/C++ Code will outperform your handwritten asm easily.

If you are interested in Assembler, try to code something like diskaccess. This is where you can gain a lot of performance.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you only use Assembler because you seem to think that this is necessary. This isn't the case. If you don't have any other reason for it (i.e. wanting to learn it), don't use Assembler here, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

For your average graphics engine, Assembler programming is completely unnecessary. Especially when it comes to a Super Mario style 2D sprite engine. Even “slow” scripting languages like Python are fast enough for such things nowadays.

Adding to that, if you don't know very precisely what you're doing, Assembler will *not* be faster than C (in fact, chances are it will be slower because you'll re-implement existing C functions less efficiently).

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing if you are already using C with DirectX, speed is not the issue, and that this is more of a learning exercise.  For 2D under Windows, C and DirectX is going to be very fast indeed, and as Konrad Rudolph points out, hand cranked assembler is unlikely to be faster than a highly optimized SDK.

From a purely educational standpoint, it is an intersting activity, but quite complex.  Back in the early days of home computers and the first PCS, the graphics screen appeared pretty much as a block of memory, where bytes corresponded to one or more coloured pixels.  By changing the value of the screen memory you could plot points, and hence lines, and on to sprites etc...  On modern PCs this tends not to be an option, in that you program a graphics card, usually via an SDK, to do the same job.  The card then does the hard work, and you are provided with a much higher level of abstraction.  If you really wanted to get a feel for what it was like back in the day, I would recommend an emulator.  For a modern game, stick with your SDKs.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to program your own 2D engine in a recent version of Directx, if you wish to investigate this avenue.   You can create a "screen space" aligned polygon, with no perspective correction, of which is texture mapped.  You can then plot your sprites on a pixel-by-pixel basis onto this texture map.

---

As for mode 13h (Peter Parker), it brings back some memories!

```
__asm
{
mov ax,0x13
int 10h           // 16-bit code only, not Windows
}
```

But of course this will fault in a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows program; 16-bit BIOS calls are not supported by the Windows kernel (which installs its own interrupt table as part of booting and switching the CPU to 64-bit mode.)

I would tend to avoid assembler with a barge pole, it can be particulary difficult to debug, and maintain; however if you wish to explore this subject in more detail, I can recommend [Michal Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book](http://www.freetechbooks.com/michael-abrash-s-graphics-programming-black-book-t78.html).  It's a bit old, but a good read and will give you some insight into graphics programming techniques before 3D hardware.

Comment: If he wants 2D, there is no need to do a texture on a 3D polygon. DirectX is not only 3D graphics, it is a collection of technologies. The 2D part is called DirectDraw.

Answer (score 2):

Assembler for graphics was because, back then, most people lacked graphics card with 3d support, so it had to be done on the CPU, not anymore. Nowadays it's about shader programming. Shader languages allow you to cuddle up with the bare metal. So if anything you should try to code your 2d graphics to be shadered base, that way the experience will have value as a career skill.

Try CUDA for a starter.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to experiment.  Take your sprite code and write in a number of forms, starting with C/GDI and C++/DirectDraw.  Don't worry about assembler yet.

DirectX is your best bet for fast action graphics.  Learn it, then figure out how to micro-optimize with assembler.  In general, assembler isn't going to make your API calls faster.  It is going to open up flexibility for faster computation for things like 3D rotation, texture mapping, shading, etc.

Start with DirectDraw.  Here's a [FAQ](http://www.mvps.org/directx/faq/direct_draw.htm).  Technically, DirectDraw is deprecated after DirectX 7, but you can still use it and learn from it.  It'll allow you direct framebuffer modification, which is what you're probably looking for.

There's some helpful tutorials and forums at [TripleBuffer Software](http://triplebuffer.devmaster.net/).

Also consider upgrading your compiler to [Visual C++ 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/).  VC++ 6 has a buggy compiler that can be problematic with trying to compile certain C++ libraries.